# Interesting Topics to Give a Seminar On?

Tags: soft-question, education

So recently I've been attending seminars for the graduate students (and VAP's) at my local university, and after yesterday's seminar, the professor asked if I would like to give a seminar next quarter; he noted that the seminar could be on any topic of my choice as long as it was relevant and interesting. The seminar groups are entitled "Fractal Research Group" and "Mathematical Physics and Dynamical Systems". These titles are fairly loose, albeit the topics still seem to relate to the group in some way.
The last few lecture titles:

*Framework for Single Image Super-resolution Methods and Digital Photograph Expansion for Natural Images*

*Applications of Quantum Complexity Theory to Parallel Computation and Public Key Cryptography*

*Interior and Trace Embedding Results for Variable Exponent Sobolev and Maz'ya Spaces 
         on "Bad" Domains*

*Pressure and Zeta Functions for Graph Directed Markov Systems*

So naturally these are high level topics (many professors and assistant professors also attend the seminars). My question is as follows:
**Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas for a topic of discussion that I can present on?**

Comment: What does complexity theory have to do with physics?

Comment: @GitGud It's quantum complexity theory so we must introduce the properties of quantum mechanics and such.

Comment: I looked at your profile and the level of questions you are asking and answering. I strongly urge you to politely decline this offer. You don't know enough math to give a talk on fractals or mathematical physics.

Comment: @Potato Please don't make assumptions. I know enough mathematics to understand all of the lecture topics thusfar, which were not, by any means, of a low level. I utilize Math SE to ask questions for the courses I'm currently in, not self-study topics.

Comment: @AnthonyPeter I'm not making assumptions. The last question you asked was fairly standard undergraduate multivariable calculus problem. Last month you asked how to define a line integral. In the summer, you were still asking about elementary problems on cross products and dot products. At this point in your life, you simply don't know enough math to give a talk on the above topics that will interest professional mathematicians. I'm not saying this to be mean, but to spare you embarrassment.

Comment: @Potato I know of such things as Sobolev Spaces, Lp spaces, fourier transforms, etc. I know mathematics up to Real Analysis, Complex Analysis, Abstract Algebra, set theory, etc. Whatever I'm missing I can simply fill in the gaps in time. I'm presenting on the topics. It does not have to be my own original research, just something that I can understand through study and present on. If you have nothing further constructive to add, please don't contribute further. Undergraduate students have given previous seminars.

Comment: @AnthonyPeter I think you should ask the professor who made you this proposition to suggest you some topics, the literature, and also be sure to have him available for numerous later explanations. Otherwise I would rather second Potato's opinion.

Comment: @O.L. The whole purpose is to present a topic that was not suggested by the professor himself, as that would prove redundant. The professor whom offered me such an honor also attends the seminars and is interested in learning rather intriguing contemporary applications of mathematics and physics, such as super-resolution of images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idea which absorbed me the last couple of years and stirred true explorative enthusiasm and joy was the concept of fractional iteration of functions, here of exponentiation (aka tetration). It has a very wide range of aspects, and fits with the subject of complex dynamics. I'm a complete amateur but it has been worth for me to become confronted with the difficulties (and partial solutions) up to undergraduate level and learn from historical articles in archived mathematical journals which can even be found online. In the "tetration-forum" there are even graduate mathematicians involved and have discussed/discuss things on higher levels (where I usually could then no more follow) and thus I think this subject has also some flair as a subject for a whole semester. Students can explore different approaches, try their own intuitive ideas and learn from detecting the subtile reasons for possible or even likely failures.

My own approach, for instance, was an accidental (re)discovery of the concept of Carleman-matrices for the composition/selfcomposition of functions - and for some of those matrices fractional powers can be defined to determine formal powerseries for fractional iteration; difficile aspects of convergence radii occur etc...

For some examples of my own exploring you might take a look at my site at the [subsection for tetration](http://go.helms-net.de/math/tetdocs/index.htm) and a very nice eyeopener is possibly [this comparision](http://go.helms-net.de/math/tetdocs/ComparisionOfInterpolations.pdf) of 4 more-or-less naive and one seriously discussed methods, the latter [namely of Hellmuth Kneser in the 40ies](http://zbmath.org/?q=an:0035.04801) of the previous century, which I'd just updated today.

If this proposal sounds as a possibly reasonable base for such a course to you, we could continue the discussion about a more precise workout of list of topics by email (or via the [tetration-forum](http://math.eretrandre.org/tetrationforum/index.php))

Answer (score 1):

If there is a paper you have heard about, it might be one that has been mentioned in several of the seminars, and you would like to read why not report on that paper? Perhaps you could find an alternative proof for one of the results.